# How to make this function more gas efficient?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-estimate

I have this function:

```
function foo(uint256 _a, uint256 _b, uint256 _c) {
    require(map[msg.sender].a == 1);
    require(map[msg.sender].b < 1);
    require(map[msg.sender].c > 1);

    deposits[msg.sender].a = _a;
    deposits[msg.sender].b = _b;
    deposits[msg.sender].c = _c;
}
```

Is this extremely wasteful?

How could i make it more gas efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could i make it more gas efficient?

You can change bits size of your `uint`'s in struct.

If you are using `uint256` you are using whole 32 byte chunk. If you were using `uint128` for example, you could fit more data in one `SSTORE` operation (due to solidity compiler optimization).

---

Let me give some examples of gas consumption:

---

**Function:**

```
function getVariables() public {
    deposits[msg.sender].a = 1;
    deposits[msg.sender].b = 1;
    deposits[msg.sender].c = 1;
}
```

**uint256 struct**

```
struct demo {
        uint256 a;
        uint256 b;
        uint256 c;
    }
```

Execution cost: **60455** gas

**uint128 struct**

```
struct demo {
        uint128 a;
        uint128 b;
        uint128 c;
    }
```

Execution cost: **46264** gas

**uint64 struct**

```
struct demo {
        uint64 a;
        uint64 b;
        uint64 c;
    }
```

Execution cost: **31314** gas

---

> If the Solidity compiler can figure out the size of store variables,
>   it simply lays them out one after another in storage. If possible, the
>   compiler packs the data tightly in chunks of 32 bytes.

From [Diving Into The Ethereum VM Part 2](https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-part-2-storage-layout-bc5349cb11b7).